BUnit razor syntax not recognized

The blazor documentation describes how this should be done. I tried :

specifying the name of the cascading parameter in both the definition. It makes sense that the names are necessary, how else would BUnit know which value should be applied to which CascadingParameter?
Deleting my .vs folder and restarting Visual Studio.
Changing the whitespace, putting the whole thing on a single line, the @ immediately after the ctx.Render(


Have you enabled the Razor compiler in your test project? To do this, you have to change the SDK type of the project, see:
https://bunit.dev/docs/getting-started/writing-tests.html?tabs=xunit#creating-basic-tests-in-razor-files
There is nothing bUnit specific with this. It is a Blazor/Razor compiler feature we are utilizing, and if the Razor compiler does not like the code you have written, we (bUnit) cannot help, unfortunately.

Yes, the project has other .razor files and unit tests in .test.razor files. I also made sure to include it in the project as Content, not Compile or None.

Can you show the first lines of your csproj file?

@MrFox "the project has other .razor files" : and do they compile correcttly?  And what exactly is marked as Content?  Try posting a [mre]

Make sure that your csproj files begins like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

The default when you create a new unit test project is "just" Microsoft.NET.Sdk.
